# AngularJs ui.bootstrap - Modal show error [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am trying to use angular `ui.bootstrap` to implement some functionality like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/DgE5eGGmGebQfWunhqqv?p=preview)  but this shows an error

> [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20ngReallyClickDirective

my code is

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router','oc.lazyLoad','ui.bootstrap','ngReallyClickModule']);
```

**ngReallyClickModule.js**

```
angular.module('ngReallyClickModule',['ui.router'])
    .directive('ngReallyClick', ['$modal',
        function($modal) {

            var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.ok = function() {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                };

                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            };

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope:{
                    ngReallyClick:"&",
                    item:"="
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.bind('click', function() {
                        var message = attrs.ngReallyMessage || "Are you sure ?";


                        var modalHtml = '<div class="modal-body">' + message + '</div>';
                        modalHtml += '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>';

                        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                            template: modalHtml,
                            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
                        });

                        modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                            scope.ngReallyClick({item:scope.item}); 
                        }, function() {
                            //Modal dismissed
                        });


                    });

                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

**View**

```
<a ng-really-message="Are you sure ?" ng-really-click="test(item)" item="item" ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5]">Delete</a>
```

i want modal dialog on `ng-really-click` click. And call a function of the current controller on click of the modal  Ok button.

i am using `angular-ui-router` and `oclazyLoading`

Comment: Assuming a moderately recent version, it's `$uibModal` and `$uibModalInstance` ~ https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is from the error, your are using some provider that you have not defined/injected.

It is hard to say exactly what is the problem considering you have many injections here, but from the error you gave us, there is no provider for `$modal`. AngularUI recently switched to `uib` prefixing most of its providers and directives (i.e. `$uibModal`). Try using the new version.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

Comment: [October 9, 2015](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/releases/tag/0.14.0) <- not recent.

Comment: Actually, support for non-prefixed components was not removed until V1.0.0.  There was a period of overlap to give folks a chance to migrate.